# Play sound while button is held down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 1.5 seconds audio file - a single gunshot sound. I want to be able to play the sound while the mouse is pressed (like an automatic weapon), and I used `InvokeRepeating` to call the shoot method, with a very low repeatRate:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
{
    InvokeRepeating("Shoot", 0f, 1f/currentWeapon.fireRate);
} else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
{
    CancelInvoke("Shoot");
}
```

And this is the Shoot method:

```
void Shoot()
{
    shootSound.PlayOneShot(shoot);
}
```

The problem is the sound cuts off and the shot can't be heard, it's playing for a fraction of a second instead of the whole audio clip. I tried play() and playOneShot().

Is there an option to play each clip to its fullest separately, like creating clones of it?

Thanks!

Comment: PlayOneShot is appropriate for use in this case but without your code, it's impossible to tell what you are doing.

Comment: I added the methods I mentioned. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: 1. No, I want them to play "on top" of each other, just start each one with each InvokeRepeating's repetition, and let it play to the end. The goal is for it to sound like a machine gun. 2. The Shoot function is the only one calling PlayOneShot(). shootSound is the AudioSource and shoot is the AudioClip. 3. It plays the sound till the end. The sound itself is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I used an empty GameObject with an AudioSource, and instantiated a copy of it in each Shoot method:

```
GameObject gunObj = Instantiate(gunObject);
Destroy(gunObj, 1f);
```

Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 2):

Most things in your code are just unnecessary. You don't need `InvokeRepeating` for this. Since you want to continue to player sound(shooting effect) while the button is held down, `Input.GetButton` should be used instead of `Input.GetButtonDown` because [`Input.GetButton`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButton.html) is true every frame the button is held down and is made for things like auto fire.

A simple timer with `Time.time` should also be used to determine the rate to play the sound then play the sound with the `PlayOneShot` function.

This is what that should look like:

```
public float playRate = 1;
private float nextPlayTime = 0;

public AudioSource shootSound;
public AudioClip shoot;


void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && (Time.time > nextPlayTime))
    {
        Debug.Log("Played");
        nextPlayTime = Time.time + playRate;
        shootSound.PlayOneShot(shoot);
    }
}
```

The `playRate` variable is set to `1` which means `1` sound per-sec. You can use this variable to control the play rate. Lower it to play many sounds. The value of `0.1f` seems to be fine but it depends on the sound.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and edits. I tried your approach, but unfortunately the sound keeps cutting off. Even when I try with a high `playRate`, like 2.5f (longer than the clip), it's still cutting off right at the beginning. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I tried it in a new test scene. The script works, but it plays the sound until the end and only then starts the next one - REGARDLESS of the `playRate`. I'm trying to find a way to play it again and again, but in "layers" - like adding a new `AudioSource` with every iteration that will play at the same time as the one before, not just loop the original sound. Hope I'm being more clear.